# Laravel Nova - How can i do custom logic on Create/Update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-nova

I would like to create custom Create/Update logic for one of my `Nova Resource`. I have been thinking to use `Custom Tools` to accomplish what i wanted, but i don't want to give up the excellent work in the `Index` page and rewrite it all myself.

My use case:

- I want to have an input that can define how many record to be created recursively.
- I want to have `morphToMany` selection input in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use different components on the index vs form/detail page just use the `hideFromIndex` and `onlyOnIndex` functions.

Detailed reference to docs: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#showing-hiding-fields

If you want to build repetitive fields, you can use the package: https://packagist.org/packages/fourstacks/nova-repeatable-fields

Comment: That will not accomplish what i want based on my use case.

Comment: As I understand your use case, you already have developed the field to create multiple records and you just want to hide from the index page. If that is true, you can just use the hideFromIndex function. If not, please explain your use case in more detail

Comment: sorry for not explaining clearly. Since u understand my use case, then those inputs are what i want to build, but i not sure which way to is better.

Comment: Have updated my answer to include how to build repeatable fields